# watch a @attribute in google chrome debugger javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Hi i have a big field of information and i am trying to access something further in the tree but it is not letting me go any further then below.

I get to:

```
  Customer().Added.customers.purchases.purchasesdetails()[0]
```

Now below that is @attributes: Object which i need to watch so i can get to the values in the object.

I have tried a few things but what is the best way to apply the @attribute to my javascript so i can access the values in that @attribute object.

If anyone knows how i can apply this so i can show this piece of information on my webpage it be a great help. Thanks Dom

Comment: You mean bracket notation? `["@attributes"]` works for property access where `.@attributes` is a syntax error. Your question is very unclear by the way - please consider copy editing it.

Comment: its single quotes ['@attributes'] fixed now thanks anyway.